# Single Sign On - check authentication server on each request

Tags: curl, single-sign-on

I am working on SSO mechanism. I have set it up and created an authentication server with login screen. The SSO should work like this (and to that point it is already working):

1. when the client app is accessed and user is not logged in, redirect to SSO Auth realm
2. on SSO Auth realm when user is not logged in, show login screen
3. after login create session variables (or when user is logged in already - session variables exist) and redirect back with token stored in session
4. when back on client app, take the token, store it into session and request user_id from the SSO Auth realm by `cURL`
5. when on client app and user is logged in repeat the point `4.` on each request to make sure the user is still logged in and perform logout on the client when server responds with false response

First 3 points are working great but I have problem with point 4 (and 5, ofc.), because it seems that when cURL requesting the SSO Auth realm, the session does not exist there (or a new one is created for cURL request).

Therefore I would like to ask:

1. **How to make the SSO Auth realm application access the existing session and return the information within the cURL response to the client app?**
2. **Or what is a better way of doing this check?**

Just a few information that is not obvious:

- all the client applications and SSO Auth realm application have their own sessions
- the reason for doing the check is to check whether the user didn't log off at different client application (session didn't expire on the SSO Auth realm) - if yes, we have to log off him at the current one as well
- by SSO Auth realm I just mean the application that is responsible for logging in the users
- the `user_id` cannot be transfered with the token directly after logging in because this would be a huge security leak - I could then make myself logged in as any possible user just by opening the client application with URL containing some random token and existing user ID...

**EDIT**: for now I have solved the issue by using the SSO Auth realm's PHPSESSID as a token. This way I can set the cookie `PHPSESSID=TOKEN` with cURL and the request now accesses the existing session, but I do not like the idea of using the realm's PHPSESSID as a token that could be seen in the URL redirects... Anybody knows about better solution?

Comment: Regarding step 4.  Why request the user_id in this step, when the SSO Auth can set a cookie with the user_id in step 3.  The cookie will be at the top domain and the value encrypted.  Of course, this only works if all your apps are in the same top domain.   On each page load you would need to validate if the user_id + token combination is valid. if not, log the person out.  that process might be too heavy for your needs, but it gets rid of having to request the user_id.

Comment: No, they are not in the top domain, the 2<sup>nd</sup> level domain may be different. Either way, this request is performed on every page-load to ensure user is not logged off at SSO server (from within a different application for example). I have it all working, but using the approach in the edited part...